# wordpress limit number of posts per category

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

how can I limit the number of posts per category in a Wordpress custom post type?

I'm making a portfolio site for a client with my own Wordpress theme. And on the homepage there are only 8 spots for "Featured" projects. When you create / update a project, you can check the category Featured. How can I make sure the category featured can't be checked more than 8 times.

Comment: Are you asking how to limit how many posts are displayed in a custom wp-query?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a function like this one

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'myposts_limit');
function myposts_limit( $query ) { 
  if( !is_admin() && is_tax( 'featured' )) { //change featured with your custom taxonomy
     $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 10); //10 posts on your custom taxonomy
   }        
}
```

If you want to limit more check the below function:

```
function myposts_limit( $query ) {
 if( $query->is_category() && !is_admin()):
    $query->set('posts_per_page', 14); //14 posts on category
   return;
 endif;
 if( $query->is_search() && !is_admin()):
    $query->set('posts_per_page', 20); //20 posts on search
   return;
 endif; 
 if( $query->is_tag() && !is_admin()):
    $query->set('posts_per_page', 30); //30 posts on tag template
   return;
 endif;  
 if( !is_admin() && is_tax( 'featured' )) { //change featured with your custom taxonomy
      $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 10); // 10 posts on your custom taxonomy
  }          
}
```